# ArrayList replacing everything before when new element is added?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm attempting to add elements into an arraylist (also append an arraylist to the other), however it seems to rewrite everything else already present in that arraylist too - so I'm left with an arraylist filled with the last element added.

Here's the method concerned:

```
private static ArrayList<Move> checkX(int r, int c) {
        ArrayList<Move> moves = new ArrayList<Move>();
        if (jumps()) { // if jumps are found && this piece can jump
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                if (Character.isLowerCase(board[r-1][c+i]) && board[r-2][c+2*i] == ' ') {
                }
            }
        } else { // if no jumps are found then move normally
            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i+=2) {
                try {
                    if (board[r-1][c+i] == ' ') {
                        Move tempMove = new Move(r, c);
                        tempMove.addDestination((r-1), (c+i));
                        moves.add(tempMove);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(moves.get(i).toString());
        }
        return moves;
    }
```

Move class:

```
public class Move {
    private static ArrayList<int[]> destinations;
    // private static char[][] tmpboard;

    public Move(int r, int c) {
        destinations = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] initSquare = {r, c};
        destinations.add(initSquare);
    }

    public void addDestination(int r, int c) {
        int[] destinationSquare = {r, c};
        destinations.add(destinationSquare);
    }

    public ArrayList<int[]> getMove() {
        return destinations;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String returnStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < destinations.size(); i++) {
            returnStr += Arrays.toString(destinations.get(i));
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
}
```

Every time I attempt to print out everything stored in an instance of 'moves' it seems to only print out the last element added to the list n times.

Comment: it would be nice to add the relevant code to this question, not some external site.

Comment: Please post your `Move` class.  Are the variables declared in `Move` `static`?

Comment: your Move object always gets the same arguments through its constructor, only second argument of addDestination() is any different between iterations. Are you sure your Move objects don't just *seem* the same when you print them out via System.out.println?

Comment: @rgettman I have posted the Move class

Comment: @user2938375: the way you've written it, all `Move` objects ever, whether in the list or not, will be the same.

Comment: Don't use static modifier without thought. You're basically shooting yourself in the foot by blindly using it for your destinations field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static ArrayList<int[]> destinations;
```

Here's your issue. Try removing the `static` modifier.

What static here means that the latest additions of destinations will affect all Move instances, which makes them identical.

It's possible you were thinking of `final` there instead, which would make more sense.